# How to export trained stable-baselines/TensorFlow neural network to MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, onnx, stable-baselines

I'm trying to export a PPO2-trained neural network to MATLAB. It was saved as a zip file using

```
model.save(os.path.join(save_dir, 'best_overall_model'))
```

I can load my model with

```
model = PPO2.load(os.path.join(load_dir), env=env, tensorboard_log=save_dir)
```

Because I could not find a direct way to do the exporting to MATLAB, I thought of using Open Neural Network Exchange (ONNX) as an intermediate format.
I could not find info on how to do this conversion from Stable Baselines, so I resaved my model with TensorFlow using `simple_save`. Note: I'm using TensorFlow 1.14.

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(model.sess, os.path.join(save_dir, 'tensorflow_model'), inputs={"obs": model.act_model.obs_ph}, outputs={"action": model.action_ph})
```

Finally, I use the following command to obtain the ONNX file:

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model tensorflow_model --output model.onnx
```

I used [netron](https://netron.app/) to visualise the resulting ONNX file. Clearly, something went wrong:
[image: ONNX]

Alternative suggestions to get my neural network into MATLAB are also appreciated.

Comment: Instead of saving your model, saving your weight of layers, [Explain](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load), Do you try this apprach? then load your weight and input each weight to same layer in matlab.

Comment: The `save_weights` function is not available. `model` is a PPO2 object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worth trying what is described [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/deep-learning/2021/04/16/bringing-tensorflow-models-into-matlab/).

To summarize/outline:

1. Save the model in HDF5 format in Python (as it seems you are using TF 1.x).
2. Load the model into Matlab using `importKerasNetwork`

For more info look here: [https://blogs.mathworks.com/deep-learning/2022/03/18/importing-models-from-tensorflow-pytorch-and-onnx/#:~:text=Importing%20TensorFlow%20Models%20using%20the%C2%A0HDF5%20(Keras)%20Format](https://blogs.mathworks.com/deep-learning/2022/03/18/importing-models-from-tensorflow-pytorch-and-onnx/#:%7E:text=Importing%20TensorFlow%20Models%20using%20the%C2%A0HDF5%20(Keras)%20Format)

Comment: stable-baselines unfortunately does not support saving to HDF5.